# Read two Line from Text file and put them in a string

Tags: java, string, file

Hi I want to read 2 lines from a text file and put them in 2 different strings, so that i can use that string in some connection with DB. I want to read the `oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver` in String 1 and `jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/XE`,`satdalal`,`satdalal` in String 2

```
try{
          File file = new File("D:\\WalletManagementSystem\\WalletManagementSystem\\config.txt");
    FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(file);
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
    StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
    String line;
        String line1;
    while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) == null) {
        stringBuffer.append(line);
        stringBuffer.append("\n");
        }
        fileReader.close();

          //Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
            Class.forName(/*String 1 to come here*/);
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(/*String 2 to come here*/);
          //Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/XE","satdalal","satdalal");
          return conn;

      } 
      catch (Exception e){
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
          return null;
}`
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you create a properties file and put 2 lines in there each separated from 'equals' sign.

For example -

```
drivername=oracle.jdbc.OracleDrive
url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/XE","satdalal","satdalal"
```

Try - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html

```
java.util.Properties p = new Properties();
p.load(new FileInputStream(new File("my_config_file.txt")));
String driverName = (String)p.get("drivername");
```

Answer (score 0):

you can just import java.util.Properties.

```
Env.class:


import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Properties;

/**
 * Created by light on 2016/6/17.
 */
public class Env {
    private static Properties prop = new Properties();
    private static Env instance = new Env();

    private Env(){
        InputStream in = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/application.properties");
        try {
            prop.load(in);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static Env getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }

    public String getProperty(String key){
        return (String) prop.get(key);
    }
}
```

and application.properties you shall set like this:

```
url = jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.80.0.189:1521:dhybzxztk
name = oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
user = *****
password = *****
```

when you use the above connection info, you can use the method like this :

```
Env env =  Env.getInstance();
String url = env.getProperty("url");
String name = env.getProperty("name");
String user = env.getProperty("user");
String password = env.getProperty("password");
```